# A way to not show 2 of 3 parameters in a url using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Category\.php\?pageNum_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&totalRows_RS_Search=([^\s&]+)&Category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Compare/%3/%2/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /Category.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$3&totalRows_RS_Search=$2&Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^Compare/([^/]+)/?$ /Category.php?pageNum_RS_Search=$3&totalRows_RS_Search=$2&Category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This gave me the dreaded 404 error page not found, also tried to remove the `%2/%1`  that would not work at all as it still needs the values.

What i'm after is my page o look as follows:

```
mysite.co.uk/Category name/
```

(not show the last 2 paramaters but still use them to trigger the right page). Is this possible using .htaccess?

Comment: For a URL `mysite.co.uk/Category name/` in browser what should be internal URI?

Comment: mysite.co.uk/Category.php?pageNum_RS_Search=1&totalRows_RS_Search=34&Category=Category name The numbers are the page numbers that are triggered dynamically. So I was hoping not to show the number so it'll look like my site.co.uk/Category name. I've just swapped the variables around in the htaccess as it initially looked better with the numbers on the end, but now i would like to if possible not show the numbers at all. Thanks again for looking

Comment: So `pageNum_RS_Search=1&totalRows_RS_Search=34` will be static (same) for any `Category=Ca‌​tegory name` OR `Category=Ca‌​tegory123`?

Comment: the numbers are created ones you go to the next page. Hope that's what you meant

Comment: Right but how will those numbers become part of your internal URI that is unclear to me.